# Adding an existing Drupal7 form field in PHP

Tags: php, drupal-7, textfield, content-type, drupal-theming

```
<?php
/** featurename.module */
function featurename_confirm_page($form, &$form_state, $node) {
  $question = t('Are you sure you want to proceed with <em>@something</em> task?', array('@something' => $node->title));
  $form = array();
  $form['#node'] = $node;
  $form['nid'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => $node->nid,
  );
  $form = confirm_form($form, $question, 'node/' .
    $node->nid, t(  (preg_match("/featurename_content_type/i", $node->type) ? 'DROP-DOWN MENU HERE: ' .
    /* (insert list text field from another content type here) */ .
    : '') .
    '<p>By proceeding you are confirming that you want to do something; click only after you have selected an option from the drop-down menu and are ready to do something.'));
  return $form;
} // end featurename_confirm_page
?>
```

Given the above, where in the documentation does it show the syntax on how to programmatically (via PHP) add an existing form field from a different content type?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are you trying to take a field that you attached to a content type, and embed it into an arbitrary form?

Comment: Maybe take a look at the field_attach API. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/group/field_attach/7

Comment: @Brian , yes; I have a content type MyContentType that contains a text list, field_mycontenttype_dropdown, and when you go to www.mywebsite.web/node/123/confirmpage, a node of featurename_content_type instead of MyContentType, I want field_mycontenttype_dropdown to appear.

Comment: SOLVED: see https://api.drupal.org/comment/40908#comment-40908